# MySQL subquery question

Tags: mysql

I am trying to accomplish something and havent been able to find out if it can be done.  I have a table "Events" that has event info.  Within that table are ID's for Associations that sponsor that event.  Sometimes it is only one and sometimes it can be as many as five.  These Associations are in the "Associations" table.  Within the Associations table, there are several details about that Association.  What I am trying to do is do a query that will search the events table, and get all of the events that are between now and the event date, as well as retrieve the information about each Association that relates to each particular event.  Here is the query that I have so far:

```
SELECT
`Events`.EventID,
`Events`.AssociationID,
`Events`.Association2ID,
`Events`.Association3ID,
`Events`.Association4ID,
`Events`.Association5ID,
`Events`.DateFrom,
`Events`.DateTo,
`Events`.EventName,
`Events`.VenueID,
`Events`.TestnTune,
`Events`.ShownShine,
`Events`.SpecialInfo,
`Events`.OtherInfo,
`Events`.Rating,
`Events`.EventOverlay,
`Events`.HavePictures,
`Events`.IncludeInSchedule,
`Events`.EventURL,
Associations.Active,
Associations.Acronym,
Associations.OrgName,
Associations.WebURL,
Associations.LogoURL,
Associations.AssociationID,
Venues.LocationName,
Venues.Location,
Venues.longetude,
Venues.latitude,
Venues.Directions,
Venues.SitePros,
Venues.SiteCons,
Venues.BasicInfo,
Venues.SiteRating,
Venues.HostedEvents,
Venues.CurrentWeather
FROM
`Events`
LEFT JOIN Associations ON `Events`.AssociationID = Associations.AssociationID AND `Events`.Association2ID = Associations.AssociationID AND `Events`.Association3ID = Associations.AssociationID AND`Events`.Association4ID = Associations.AssociationID AND `Events`.Association5ID = Associations.AssociationID
LEFT JOIN Venues ON `Events`.VenueID = Venues.VenueID
WHERE
`Events`.DateFrom >= NOW()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to model an many-to-many relationship by using several 1-n relationships and naming them association1, association2, etc... That's probably not a good idea.

Create a new entity called EventToAssociation (or similar), holding foreign keys to both events, and association. Then, your joins will be a lot easier to create.

In an example query, this would read:

```
SELECT *
FROM Event e
JOIN EventToAssociation e2a ON e.EventID = e2a.EventID
JOIN Association a ON e2a.AssociationID = a.AssociationID
```

If changing the schema is not an option, then you'll have to join Association several times to Event, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Event e
LEFT OUTER JOIN Associations a1 ON e.AssociationID = a1.AssociationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Associations a2 ON e.Association2ID = a2.AssociationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Associations a3 ON e.Association3ID = a3.AssociationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Associations a4 ON e.Association4ID = a4.AssociationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Associations a5 ON e.Association5ID = a5.AssociationID
```

Comment: I have real basic MySQL knowledge so some of this goes over my head.  Not sure what the e is for after FROM Event e?  Also, this would be a many to one relationship.  The Events table refers to the Association table sometimes 5 times.  Sorry if I sound like an idiot, for some reason just not grasping it.

Comment: Don't worry, that's why you ask :-). So e is an alias for event. It is a common practice in SQL to provide aliases for tables/fields in your query and use those, instead of the fully qualified object names. E.g. once you select from Event e (or Event AS e), you can then access Event fields using e.EventID, instead of Event.EventID. This is necessary if you do multiple joins of the same table, when you join Association several times. The thing about the relational data model is a bit more tricky to explain, however... try the second query I suggested and SELECT * from it to see what happens

Comment: Oh, I know what you have to do in addition. Make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. See my edited answer. An outer join is like an "optional" join

Comment: Ok so what I have done is added the second query you posted, but now getting an error that says

Comment: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Events.EventID' in 'field list

Comment: If you have aliases in your query, then you MUST use those aliases. i.e. write e.EventID. But in any case, to see what happens, SELECT * and then draw your own conclusions

Comment: Are there aliases for the Associations, and Venues tables as well?  It is throwing an error now that says [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Associations.Active' in 'field list'.  Is that where I refer to a1, a2, a3 etc?

Comment: Exactly. I left out Venues, as I thought you'd figure that out yourself. So if you explicitly want to select fields from the 5 associations you will have to do that using a1.Active, a2.Active, etc. Then you can define more aliases for the various Active fields, such as `SELECT a1.Active a1_Active, a2.Active a2_Active`, etc

Comment: Excellent, I did get it to produce results, but for some reason it is only showing me (1) result.  There should be about (14).  I think I figured it out.  There needed to be LEFT JOIN, not just JOIN, because some of the Events will only have (1) Association that is related to it.

Comment: Lukas, thank you so much for you time helping me.  I get it now! I learned a lot from this little question.  Will help me on some other projects I have on the same website.  5 Stars on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every join you make is between your Events-Table and the same Associations-Table. This is just like an AND-Condition.

#### Try using Aliases:

```
LEFT JOIN Associations Asso1 ON `Events`.AssociationID = Asso1.AssociationID
LEFT JOIN Associations Asso2 ON `Events`.Association2ID = Asso2.AssociationID
```